# What is a HP Smart Array P822 Transient Data Drive

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

We had a disk go bad on one of our HP servers. It is a RAID 60. We had 2 drives in the system that weren't assigned to an array yet. We rebooted went into the array and clicked the failed/BAD drive. We then selected "replace drive" (I think it was called something else but can't remember exactly), and then selected one of the two drives that was unassigned.

We ended up getting a new drive shortly after (as in a few hours) and went ahead and replaced the BAD drive with the new drive. The system was still doing rebuild when we replaced the drive.

At this point its still doing a rebuild but the new drive now shows up as

`physicaldrive 2E:2:4 (port 2E:box 2:bay 4, SATA, 3 TB, Transient Data Drive)`

What does a `Transient Data Drive` mean?

Currently it is

`logicaldrive 2 (54.6 TB, RAID 60, Transforming, 0.41% complete)` looks like its going to be there awhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transient Data Drive means that data is being transferred from/to that drive. Once the "Transformation" is complete, the drive will change its state to "Ok".

In my use case, I was moving a logical drive from one HDD array to a SSD array. The HDD drives moved to the SSD array and they status was exactly that "Transient Data Drive" with a green arrow icon on the side.

[Moving logical drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3coG.png)

Hope this helps.

(I know this is an old question but answering anyway for future reference.)